# Changing external CSS is not reflected in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some elements in a page. It creates based on the CSS. I have dynamically change the style sheet by appending the link tag in head using JavaScript. The link tag appended perfectly. But my problem is the style sheet is not loaded at the time of element creation. So my calculation and all were wrong. Style sheet is loaded at last after all my process completes. 
Is there any way to change style sheet will reflect the DOM ???

I have a div element ("sat") in this page.

HTML File

```
$(function () {
    $('head').append($('<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>')); // insert style sheet as a link tag
    var ht = $("#sat").height();
    $("#sat").height(ht+200);    
});
```

CSS file

```
.dummy {
   height: 100px;
   background-color: red;
}
```

The div element shows height of 200px insteadof 300px. Since the css is not loaded in the time of calculation

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: How on earth are we supposed to help you with the information you provided?

Comment: HTML File
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
   $('head').append($('<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>'));
            var ht = $("#sat").height();
   $("#sat").height(ht+200);
        });
 </script>
    <div id="sat" class="dummy"/>
</body>

CSS file
.dummy {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}

The div element shows height of 200px insteadof 300px. Since the css is not loaded in the time of calculation

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to load CSS dynamically, insert a `link` tag with `onload=` and continue processing in a separate function.